# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when filling input fields using webview

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uiwebview, exc-bad-access

Very strange problem here.  I have an app that's entirely based on webview (it just serves up a mobile site).  I recently encountered a very strange EXC_BAD_ACCESS issue while running the app in the emulator.

On the login page (which is the "landing" page for the app i.e. it's shown when the app first starts) there's no problem, but on all other pages, **when I go to input text in an input field, the app crashes with the EXC_BAD_ACCESS error**.  Sometime this happens as soon as I type the first letter, sometimes after about two letters in.

Here's the line it's implicating when it crashes (not sure if this means anything in particular):

```
int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);
```

Any ideas?  If you need more details about the app/code snippets, let me know.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post the entire stack trace the debugger shows you?

Comment: Try enable NSZombie objects in scheme in diagnostics section.

Comment: Here's a general tip that could help you: add an exception break point to your code, so that the code will break where the exception is being thrown instead of in main. Here are concise instructions on how to do this: http://bencollier.net/2011/11/xcode-4-2-doesnt-show-exception-stack-trace-in-console/

Comment: So I tried to set the exception break point, but it's still breaking at the same spot.  How do I best show you the stack?